# How can I make my jQuery slideshow work?

Tags: jquery

I want to have a visual portfolio displaying a list of projects. When a project's title is clicked, a large image (imgdefault in the code below), miniature image (miniatures) and description (description) are displayed at the same time.

#### The code generated by PHP

```
<section id="slide">
    <ul id="imgdefaut">
        <li><img src="GdeImg0.jpg" /><img src="GdeImg1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="GdeImg2.jpg" /><img src="GdeImg3.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="miniatures">
        <li><img src="miniaturesImg0.jpg" /><img src="miniaturesImg1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="miniaturesImg2.jpg" /><img src="miniaturesImg3.jpg" /></li>       
    </ul>
    <ul id="description">
        <li>Description Images 0</li>
        <li>Description Images 1</li>   
    </ul>
</section>
```

In jQuery, the beginning of my function works but I used `.eq()` and `.index()`.

#### My jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#listeProjet ul li").click(function () {
         $("#imgdefaut > li:not(li:nth-child(1)) > img").css({'visibility':'hidden'});
         $("#miniatures > li:not(li:nth-child(1))").css({'visibility':'hidden'});
         $("#description > li:not(li:nth-child(1))").css({'visibility':'hidden'});              
    },function(){
         $("#imgdefaut > li:not(li:nth-child("+ $(this).index().next("li") +")) > img").css({'visibility':'visible'});
         $("#miniatures > li:not(li:nth-child("+ $(this).index().next("li") +"))").css({'visibility':'visible'});
         $("#description > li:not(li:nth-child("+ $(this).index().next("li") +"))").css({'visibility':'visible'});                            
    });           
});
```

With no results. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Anglais est la lingua franca de StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi @user2102302. In general, Stack Exchange [expects people to use English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) - we're not a multilingual site and don't attempt to be. If you prefer speaking French I suggest you find a French speaking programming forum; otherwise please write your post in English.

Comment: `$(this).index().next("li")` will return the next li sibling, overriting the return value of your index call so when evaluated your selector is actually something like: `#description > li:not(li:nth-child([object Object])`

Comment: Thankx .. my english sometimes is so bad. but would love to be bilangual ...

Comment: @user2102302: google translated would be enough to give us native speakers the gist...

Comment: Come on Zenith ... french, english ... it's not the subject.

Comment: @user2102302 'Tis the subject :) That's the only reason the others closed your question. Now hopefully we can get it back open.

Comment: I've submitted an English edit by putting what you wrote through Google Translate. Some words might have been lost in translation - the "Without results" bit doesn't make sense in English, and I don't want to assume you're trying to say "I'm not getting the result I want", so please review my edit!

Comment: Thankx my friend : "I'm not getting the result I want" --> I can't get the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in a comment to your question, your `nth-child` query is wrong and will not produce a correct index number (if you check the javascript console you'll see an error in jQuery's selector).

Your best bet is to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Initially hide all elements except the first of each <ul>
   $('#slide li:not(:first-child)').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});

   // Create click event for selector (in this case a simple <ul>).
   $('#selector li').click(function() {
      // Hide all elements
      $('#slide li').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
      // Store the index of the current element
      var index = $(this).index();
      // For each <ul>, make the i-th element visible.
      $('#slide ul').each(function() {
         $(this).children('li:eq(' + index + ')').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
      });
   });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle that implements the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HmWvk/).

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted ! Thankx so much !!